# Fancybox data-fancybox-type="iframe" and Strict XHTML Doctype

Tags: fancybox-2

Is there a way to use `data-fancybox-type="iframe"` with strict xhmtl at all so that it validates? I have everything working except for that error that I get.

Is there a way to write it so that it works with my current doctype?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `data-*` attribute validates only with HTML5, you may prefer to use the fancybox special *class* to set the content `type`, so instead of this :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="page.html">open</a>
```

... try :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="page.html">open</a>
```

... then your document will validate with your current DOCTYPE and it will have exactly the same effect.